# How to fix "Duplicate content roots detected path in React native android studio?"

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I have been getting the below warning while syncing the gradle in Android studio.

```
[E:/ReactNative/EGTKT_Counter_Operator_App/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/build/generated/source/codegen/java] of module [egtkt_counter_operation.react-native-screens.main] was removed from modules [egtkt_counter_operation.react-native-screens.main]
```

How to solve this issue?